# how to make consecutive DWR calls within sub process

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, dwr

Hi i want to make nested dwr call.

In my java code i have two function

```
public String getNetworks() {
   // return some networks. 
}

public String getInternalNetwork(network) {
   // return some networks. 
}
```

I want to make a chained dwr call.

```
myDwr.getNetworks({
  callback: function() {
       var network
      /// parse out answer. 
      myDwr.getInternalNetwork(network, {
      callback:function() {
      });
  }   
});
```

how do i do this so that dwr calls are made in order, and both functions are executed.

Answer (score 0):

my answer was to store the network in a different call.

```
DWREngine.beginBatch();
myDwr.getNetworks({
   callback: function(networks) {
       network = getMainNetwork(networks);
   }
});
myDwr.getInternalNetwork(network, {
   callback: function() {
   }
});
DWREngine.endBatch();
```